# How to process a task of arbitrary size using CUDA?

Tags: cuda, gpgpu, nvidia

I'm starting to learn CUDA, and have to dive straight into a project, so  I currently am lacking a solid theoretical background; I'll be picking it up along the way.

While I understand that the way the hardware is built requires the programmer to deal with thread blocks and grids, I haven't been able to find an answer to the following questions in my introductory book:

- What happens when the task size is greater than the amount of threads a GPU can process at a time? Will the GPU then proceed through the array the same way a CPU would, i.e. sequentially?
- Thus, should I worry if the amount of thread blocks that a given task  requires exceeds the amount that can simultaneously run on the GPU? I've found a notion of the "thread block limit" so far, and it's obviously higher that what a GPU can be processing at a given moment in time, thus, is that the real (and only) limit I should be concerned with?
- Other than choosing the right block size for the given hardware, are there any problems to consider when setting up a kernel for execution? I'm at loss regarding launching a task of arbitrary size. Even considered going OpenCL instead of CUDA because there appears to be no explicit block size calculation involved when launching a kernel to execute over an array.

I'm fine with this being closed as duplicate in case it is, just be sure to point at the original question.

Comment: I'd appreciate if the downvoters left notes as to what they dislike about the question, thank you. The question is very exact, not sure why it is voted as being too broad.

Comment: I voted to close it as too broad. Because it is. You have effectively asked four different questions, and answering them all would require a *very* long response. Certainly longer than I am willing to write.

Answer (score 1):

The number of thread blocks can be arbitrary. The hardware can handle them sequentially if the number is large. This link gives you a basic view.

http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#scalable-programming-model

On the other hand you could use limited number of threads to handle task of arbitrary sizes by increasing the work per thread. This link shows you how to do that and why it is better.

https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/cuda-pro-tip-write-flexible-kernels-grid-stride-loops/

You may want to read the following two for a full answer.

http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html

http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-best-practices-guide/index.html